# BrightPi or Noir cam owner? Dimensions please

Tags: pi-zero

Huge thanks in advance if you are able to spare a few seconds to answer a couple of very simple questions I have spent literally dozens of hours researching.

I'm desperately trying to find out the outer dimensions and inner hole diameter of the bright pi?

Also, the diameter of the camera lens on the Noir camera?

Finally, how do people generally find imperative dimensions like this as they do not appear to be freely published for any of the parts that I'm researching?

Cheers all!

Comment: Camera documentation including mechanical drawings with dimensions here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.